# MySQL query question

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can tell my MySQL query to start from a specific id and end at another using MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `where id between x and y`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

update according to the remark

one option : `where id =x or id = y` .
second option : `where id in (x,y)`

Comment: what if I just want what those two ids are related too and nothing else.

Comment: one option : where id =x or id = y . 2 option : where id in (x,y)

Answer (score 0):

Using between operator you can achieve what you want.

### syntax:

SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE id BETWEEN 'x' AND 'y'